# Responsive not two parts of the site (box and menu )?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First problem:

But I got up very little browser when I got up out of his images on the picture falls off the box that I've shown you pictures

Main site: [drumbi](http://drumbi.com/)

Second problem:

As you can see in my picture I drew a line on the menu to the menu when I was very little, I got browser menu I was like why not?

[**Jsffidle**](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/5ymMe/1/)

[**Image1**](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/oqgxh1usaszmb8u/3-menu.JPG)

[**Image2**](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/x82kl5y2lt7e66p/2-eshteb.JPG)

[**Image3**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r12f3fbkzwajprp/1-correct.JPG)

```
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                <img class="img-responsive" style="width: 150px" src="images/websitelogo.png" alt="logo" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-menu">

                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">About </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help </a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Sign In </a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="container">

        <h1 class="voice-support">A Voice Experience Built for Support</h1>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="well box-main col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
                <h2>See how it works!</h2>
                <a class="btn  btn-lg btn-blue btn-block">Contact Us</a>
                <a class="btn  btn-lg btn-orange btn-block">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```